# How to stop a command after a certain time in bash

Tags: bash

In bash, I'm running `iftop` tool with text output. It's a tool that is monitoring network and writting the results periodicaly in the standard output (by default the terminal but could be something else, a file). It's running in foreground until I stop it with `ctrl + C`

I would like to make it running for a certain period of time (1 minute for example), and then stop the process automatically

How can I make this in bash ?

Here is what I already tried:

`sudo iftop -nNPt -L 100 -i wlp0s20f3 > iftop.out & pid=$!; sleep 20; sudo kill $pid`

But, 1) it does not kill the process and 2) it does not redirect to the file

Comment: Could it be that the output goes to stderr, and not stdout? As for "stop after a certain time", have a look at [`timeout`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html).

Comment: Thanks I did not know this function. I tried and it seems to do what I'm looking for!

Comment: @BenjaminW. is right. You can find good information about timeout [here](https://linuxize.com/post/timeout-command-in-linux/)

Comment: You can use `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file. For timeout, like others have mentioned, `timeout` is simple and best.

Answer (score 3):

Using the timeout command in Linux should work, the syntax is below,

`timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try putting everything after `&` in the next line. For this, you'll have to put the whole commands in a function in your `.bashrc` or in a script :

```sh
sudo iftop -nNPt -L 100 -i wlp0s20f3 > iftop.out &
pid=$!; sleep 20; sudo kill $pid
```